# Adapter для GridView не работает

Tags: java, android, adapter, gridview

Я делаю календарь с помощью GridView, но я не могу правильно сделать Adapter для Gridview, поэтому приложение постоянно вылетает.

класс CalendarActivity.java

```
public class CalendarActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private CalendarAdapter СAdapter;
    ArrayList <String> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);
        

        GridView g = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.calendar_grid);

// если убрать все последующие 5 строк, то все работает
        list=new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1, "2");
        g.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.cell, list)); 
        g.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        g.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
// get dates
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

класс CalendarAdapter.java

```
public class CalendarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
//    ArrayList<String> daysOfMonth;

    Context CContext;

    public CalendarAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> daysOfMonth) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, daysOfMonth);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.CContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_calendar, null);
        return v;
    }
}
  cell.xml
сомневаюсь, что проблема тут, но вдруг
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/llBtnParent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cellTxt"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

файл с GridView для календаря calendar_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/calendar_prev_button"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/date_display"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/calendar_prev_button"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/calendar_prev_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/month_year_display"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="August, 2021"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:textColor="#222222"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/calendar_next_button"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/date_display"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/date_display"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendar_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="MON"
            android:textColor="#222222" />
// и так все дни едели
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:columnWidth="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
09/04 17:29:32: Launching 'app' on Pixel 2 API 27.
Install successfully finished in 3 s 379 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 5347 on device 'Pixel_2_API_27 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x98e26740, tid 5364
I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa35e3680: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa35e3680: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x882cc9c0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa35e3680: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x882cc9c0)
D/ContentValues: onAdapterClick: clicked.2
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 5347
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.CalendarActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:483)
        at com.example.myapp.CalendarActivity.onCreate(CalendarActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 12428(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 1559KB/3MB, paused 273us total 151.490ms
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=10KB, data=21KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=10KB, data=21KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
    Do partial code cache collection, code=10KB, data=38KB
    After code cache collection, code=10KB, data=38KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
    JIT allocated 71KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
    Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
```

Comment: "постоянно вылетает." вылетает? Ошибка в логах пишется? Если да, то без нее будет сложнее разобраться в том, что у вас не так. Потому приложите листинг ошибки.

Comment: Метод getCount() должен возвращать количество элементов списка (в вашем случае размер коллекции daysOfMonth), а не этот же метод суперкласса . Но и в этом случае ничего работать не будет, так как адаптер помимо инфлейта айтема должен в него и биндить какие то данные, у вас же это отсутствует. Лучше всего прочитать несколько уроков по созданию адаптеров, так как здесь я указал только две явных проблемы и неизвестно, сколько их еще появится, исправив эти.